# Finding mclaurin expansion for $f(x,y) = \log(1-x-y+xy)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

As the title mentions, I am trying to find the McLaurin Expansion of $f(x,y)$. My approach is finding the expansion for the function $f(x) = \log(1+x)$, the replacing $x$ with $(-x-y+xy)$. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: You can also use equality $\log (1-x-y+xy)=\log (1-x)+\log(1-y)$.

Comment: Are they both correct?

Answer (score 1):

The standard logarithm expansion is given by

\begin{equation}
\log(1-x) = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}, \qquad |x|<1
\end{equation}

Write $$\log (1-x-y+xy) = \log (1-x) + \log (1-y)$$